# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64,64,4) into shape (64,64)

Tags: python, numpy

I can't convert list to array here:

```
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
```

where X and y are:

```
X = []
y = []

for fName in imgFiles:
    X_i = Image.open(fName)
    X_i = np.array(X_i.resize((64,64)))/255.0
    eList = fName.split(os.path.sep)
    X.append(X_i)
    label = eList[1].split('_')
    fLabel = label[6].split('.')
    y.append(fLabel[0])
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-6c4156275ea8> in <module>()
----> 1 X = np.array(X)
      2 y = np.array(y)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (64,64,4) into shape (64,64)
```

I think that at least one image has different dimensions but how to fix this.

Comment: At which line of code are you facing the issue? Can you also mention the error displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because not all elements of the list X are 3-dimensional. This seems to be the case because some of your image files might be grayscale and others might be non-grayscale.

Ensure that all elements of the list X are of the same dimension and this issue should be resolved.

Comment: All images were in .BMP and I changed them to .pgm for greyscale, Now if I want to check the size of all images in a directory, what do you suggest to use?